# Отрисовка в заданной области на сanvas

Tags: canvas, javascript, html5

Как в html5 canvas рисовать в заданной области? Т.е. размер самого канваса 500 на 500 пикселей.

В нём я рисую различные элементы - изображения, геометрические фигуры, текст и т.д. эти элементы могут быть любого размера.

Но сама задача заключается в том чтобы отрисовывать элементы не на весь канвас, а в прямоугольнике размером 200 на 200 в заданных координатах относительно канваса.

Конечно можно стирать лишнее после отрисовки при помощи clearRect, но возможно есть способ не делать лишней работы?

Comment: как вариант можно так же использовать globalCompositeOperation

Comment: fps до 20 падает, но отображает всё как нужно...

Comment: Я всё же разобрался. Фпс падал из-за rect, по всей видимости каждый тик я его записывал в контекст. Всего навсего нужно было перед rect сохранить контекст и после всех масок и отрисовок восстановить, вот и всё)) Спасибо всем за помощь :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ctx.clip()](http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2013/january/an-example-of-the-html5-canvas-clip-function.html)

> The clip() function of HTML5 canvas is a lesser known method that can be very useful when drawing on your canvas. You can create a path but not fill() or stroke() it and then use the clip() function so that any further drawing is restricted to that area. There's a step-by-step example of using it below. One common use for it would be to achieve "inner shadows" - as in the circle shown below - meaning that you get a bevelled appearance.

Comment: спасибо, в гугле сам не нашел почему-то))

Comment: мдааа... ну и корявый же метод)) работает не так как ожидается

Comment: А что не так?

Comment: маску можно задать только один раз,
ожидалось что можно задавать его отдельно для каждой отрисовки, но нет... или я чего-то не понимаю

на wiki есть все методы контекста и там я нашел метод resetClip, но оказалось, что его нет

Comment: Попробуй так:

ctx.save();
// ...
ctx.clip();
// draw
ctx.restore();

Comment: пробовал, этот код выполнялся каждый тик и в конечном итоге fps падает, как будто clip добавляет объекты куда-то и их со временем становится очень много... можно в общем сделать так: если изображение не попадает в область видимости, то ничего не делать, а если попадает, то вычислять видно ли оно полностью или только часть и если видна только часть, то стереть не нужное, правда боюсь, что такой подход очень ресурсоемкий... хотя не так уж и много изображений придется просчитывать каждый кадр, если работать только с теми, что попали в область видимости... но всё равно попахивает костылями :)